# Overlay div not showing if ng-if is true

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a page that has a responsive menu, with a gray overlay that's triggered if the menu is active. I've been trying to show this overlay using `ng-if`, but without success. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<header ng-controller="NavController">
    <div class="cover-header">
        <!-- Burger menu icon placement -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="collapsed nav-burger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu"
                    aria-expanded="{{showOverlay}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
</header>


<div class="container-burger-menu">
    <div class="collapse container-accordion" id="main-menu">
        <!-- menu items go here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay-nav" ng-if="showOverlay">
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay-nav {
    //display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function NavController($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('showOverlay', function(){
        console.log("value is ", $scope.showOverlay);
        $scope.showOverlay = !$scope.showOverlay;
    });
}
```

Prior to using `$scope.$watch`, I've tried something like this:

```
function NavController($scope) {
    $scope.toggleOverlay = function() {
        $scope.showOverlay = !$scope.showOverlay;
    }
}
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="collapsed nav-burger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu"
                aria-expanded="{{showOverlay}}" ng-click="toggleOverlay()>
```

Any replies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** My latest attempt:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="collapsed nav-burger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu"
                    ng-click="toggleOverlay()">

<!-- overlay -->
<div class="overlay-nav" ng-if="nav.showOverlay">
```

**Controller**

```
function NavController($scope) {

    $scope.nav = { showOverlay: '' };

    $scope.toggleOverlay = function() {
        $scope.nav.showOverlay = !$scope.nav.showOverlay;
    }
}
```

`$scope.nav.showOverlay` changes values just fine, but is not getting picked up by `ng-if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overlay isn't inside the scope of your controller, so it can't access `showOverlay`.

To fix it, move the `ng-controller`-directive into a container element instead. Like this:

```
<div ng-controller="NavController">
    <header>
        <div class="cover-header">
            <!-- Burger menu icon placement -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="collapsed nav-burger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu"
                        aria-expanded="{{showOverlay}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container-burger-menu">
        <div class="collapse container-accordion" id="main-menu">
            <!-- menu items go here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-nav" ng-if="showOverlay">
</div>
```

Comment: Gah, and all this time I thought there was something wrong with my controller. Thank you Nikolaj, it's working fine now. :)